# Iterating Through a list with functions Type Error

Tags: python, list, function

I am pretty new to python I have been learning on udemy and just playing around in my spare time. I am using some functions that generate dict/list. I am having issues with a "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

```
error, botlist = bots(None)
for bot in botlist:
    print(bot.get('id'))
    print(type(bot.get('id')))

for bot in botlist:
    botid = bot.get('id')
    print(type(bot.get('id')))

    error, dealsa = dealsa(botid)

    my_list = []
    for deal in dealsa:
        my_list.append(f"id:{deal.get('id')} name:{deal.get('bot_name')} finished?:{deal.get('finished?')} bot_id:{deal.get('bot_id')}")  
        myfile=open(f"{deal.get('bot_id')}_active.txt","w")
        myfile.write('\n'.join(my_list))
        myfile.close()

    error, dealsf = dealsf(botid)

    my_list = []
    for deal in dealsf:
        my_list.append(f"id:{deal.get('id')} name:{deal.get('bot_name')} finished?:{deal.get('finished?')} bot_id:{deal.get('bot_id')}")  
        myfile=open(f"{deal.get('bot_id')}_history.txt","w")
        myfile.write('\n'.join(my_list))
        myfile.close()
```

So saving of the text files work. If I remove the bot in botlist loop and just manually set an id it will create the text files correctly. When I try to run it in the for loop I get the type error. But it does list the bot id's from the print function then creates the first set of text files. The print function int results are the correct integers that I need to feed into the botid of the deala and dealsf functions. Im guessing I am doing the iteration wrong but not sure how to correct it.  Here is the current output:

```
2649989
<class 'int'>
2642117
<class 'int'>
2628896
<class 'int'>
2555868
<class 'int'>
2536597
<class 'int'>
2481665
<class 'int'>
2392904
<class 'int'>
2367291
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 79, in <module>
    error, dealsa = dealsa(botid)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I am really confused as to why the first print for loop works but the second one throws the type error.

Comment: Apparently `dealsa` is a list and you can't call lists like a function. But you didn't show the relevant part of the code where `dealsa` is defined, so we can't tell you more.

Comment: Assuming that you have in fact a function called `dealsa` which returns a tuple where the second item is a list, it would help if you didn't name that list the same as the function.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue happens on this line:

```
error, dealsa = dealsa(botid)
```

Here you're replacing the `dealsea` function with (part of) the return value from calling it. When you try to call the function again later (on a subsequent iteration), you're getting the earlier result (a list) instead of the function you want.

The solution is not very complicated, just pick a different name for either the function or the list. You also have the same issue happening with `dealsf` in the later part of the code. It's not raising an exception yet because you don't get to it, but if you fix only `dealsa` you'll start crashing there instead.

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize this was an issue. Good catch. It is now working. I didnt include the functions because they use a library specific to an api of a program. I don't know that they would have helps and you couldn't run the code without the credentials. Here is one of the functions for the record. They are all similar
def dealsf(bot_id):
    error, bot_info = p3cw.request(
        entity="deals",
        action="",
        payload = {
        "limit": 1000,
        "offset": 0,
        "bot_id": bot_id,
        "scope": "finished",

        }
    )
    return error, bot_info